# Query optimization with variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

First, I apologize if this question is a common one... I can't seem to find the correct terms to search...

I have a somewhat large table that has an incremental ID and an inserted `datetime` value. There are a couple indexes on it, including a primary key on the `ID` and an non-clustered index on the inserted time and ID.  So, when I write a query like the following, it's very quick:

```
select min(ID), max(ID)
from tbl
where inserted between '2015-10-07' and '2015-10-08'
```

However, if I variablize the where clause conditions (as below), it's quite a bit slower:

```
declare @sTime datetime, @eTime datetime
select @sTime = '2015-10-07', @eTime = '2015-10-08'

select min(ID), max(ID)
from tbl
where inserted between @sTime and @eTime
```

When I look at the two query plans I see the obvious problem. The first query utilizes a single `seek` on the non-clustered index of the inserted time and ID.  However, the second query instead performs 2 `scans` on the primary key (which is just the ID).

So, my question is two-fold:

1. Why is SQL Server performing these optimizations, and
2. how can I fix it?

Comment: [Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#varparamreplace) the resulting stand-alone query is quite different, and SQL Server can make **more accurate estimates with constants instead of variables**, and therefore arrive at a better plan. You can try forcing to use different plan with [Plan Guides](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#planguides)

Comment: Simply the point is that depending on data range query optimizer has to choose between index seek vs index scan.

Comment: @lad2025, while I don't think that parameters link has anything to do with my scenario (this isn't a stored procedure), it sounds like the `option(recompile)` should work in MSSQL 2008 and newer... which at least implies there's a reasonable solution moving forward...

Comment: This has not to be stored procedure. Local variable is has the same bahaviour as described in link above. Think for a moment when you pass a constant in your case one day range query optimizer know that it is narrow and use index seek. When you pass variables it tries to make universal execution plan.

Comment: See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd432d12-f296-4f94-9c33-5d2670c7fee7/performance-impact-constant-value-vs-variable?forum=transactsql) exactly the same question as yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from an implicit `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` by using the local variables.  See [this link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/stored-procedure-execution-with-parameters-variables-and-literals/) for more information.  The optimizer cannot parameter sniff the local variables and is using a general plan based on averages.  When using constants it is able to use better statistical data and optimize by using the seeks.

To fix this you may want to create a stored procedure and provide parameters instead of variables.  You may need to add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint as well to get the similar optimizations as when using constants.  Otherwise you will be subject to whatever parameters were sniffed during the first execution.

Comment: This appears to be exactly the case.  Simply changing the variables to be input parameters of a stored proc resulted in the correct optimization.

Comment: "a general plan based on averages" - what are those averages? averages of what?

Comment: The averages are based on the density_vector component of the statistics on your table.  SQL Server uses this in an attempt to create an execution plan that is "good enough" while having incomplete information of the parameters.